# Error only one device : open() failed: Operation not permitted Path: default.realm.lock

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm, realm-mobile-platform

static func realmConfig() -> Realm.Configuration {

```
    var config = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 6, migrationBlock: { (migration, oldSchemaVersion) in
        /// Migration block. Useful when you upgrade the schema version.
        
    })
    
    config.fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "realm")!
    print(config.fileURL)
    let folderPath = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().path
    let lockPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default.realm", withExtension: "lock")!.path
    do {
        try FileManager.default.setAttributes([FileAttributeKey.protectionKey: FileProtectionType.none],ofItemAtPath: folderPath)
        try FileManager.default.setAttributes([FileAttributeKey.protectionKey: FileProtectionType.none],ofItemAtPath: lockPath)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Realm initialization failed, Error:\(error)")
    }
    
    return config
}

private static func realmInstance() -> Realm {
    do {
        let newRealm = try Realm(configuration: realmConfig())
        return newRealm
    } catch {
        print(error)
        fatalError("Unable to create an instance of Realm")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wait, why are you trying to open a `.lock` file?

Comment: If data are encrypted, you can't read the file.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. If you've added a Realm to your App Bundle there would be no need to involve the Filemanager (as shown by the code in your question). Additionally, you *never* need to do anything with the .lock file and if Realm is part of your app bundle, there won't be a .lock file anyway. All you need to do to access the bundled Realm is use the line of code in your question `config.fileURL = Bundle.main...`. Is there something we're not understanding? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @aheze i am not trying to open al lock file. I am trying to create a Realm instance from config with a specific URL that is in my bundle.

Comment: @Jay the filemanager is to give permissions to the parent folder.. what i did that i copied all the files that were generated before and added them to iOS app project and try to access them. the weird thing is it is working only on simulator. i tried to delete .lock file same result

Comment: *to the parent folder.* if you're accessing a bundled Realm, there is no parent folder... what are you trying to do there? Also, why are you referencing the lock file at all - that's an 'under the hood' file Realm uses - you would generally have no interaction with it. Lastly *I am trying to create a Realm* - there's nothing in the provided code that would do that. Can you clarify what you're trying to do - give us the 'big picture' and be sure to include code that's applicable to the question.

Comment: @Jay parent folder is AppName.app...updated the question. check the full code. 

I have generated .realm files from a macOS application and added the files to iOS project.

I was able to access the default.realm when i used the above code running it on a  simulator.. but when i run it on iPhone i am getting the  error. I am NOT trying to access the lock file. the error is this... i saw some post that giving permission to the parent folder will fix the issue. but it didnt

Comment: **I am NOT trying to access the lock file.** but the code has this `let lockPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default.realm", withExtension: "lock")!` so... you're attempting to change the attributes (accessing) the .lock file and there's no reason to do that.

Comment: did you solve this issue? 
I check every thing on internet even GitHub but no solution available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The realm .lock file is an under the hood file used only by realm. You will never need to work with that file directly or bundle it when using a bundled realm. All that's needed the the realm file itself, dragged into the XCode project.

Here's how to access a bundled Realm called `MyBundledData.realm`:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    // Get the URL to the bundled file
    fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyBundledData", withExtension: "realm"),
    // Open the file in read-only mode as application bundles are not writeable
    readOnly: true)

// Open the Realm with the configuration
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

that should be all that's needed

Comment: strangely it worked when i added readonly = true !

Answer (score 0):

Try to add NSFileProtectionNone on parent directory
let realm = try! Realm()

// Get our Realm file's parent directory
let folderPath = realm.configuration.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().path

// Disable file protection for this directory
try! FileManager.default.setAttributes([FileAttributeKey(rawValue: NSFileProtectionKey): NSFileProtectionNone],
ofItemAtPath: folderPath)